# it says the UISegmentedControl has "no member selectedSegmentIndex", what do I do to make it a member?

Tags: ios

```
   @IBAction func segmentedControl(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    let number1 = Int(label1.text!)!
    let number2 = Int(label1.text!)!
    let chosenSegment = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
    
    
    
    here
      v
    let selectedSegmentIndex = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex
    if selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        ^
```

this line of code

```
    result = number1 + number2
    } else if selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
    result = number1 - number2
    } else if selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
    result = number1 * number2
    } else if selectedSegmentIndex == 3 {
    result = number1 / number2}
    }
```

i am really confused with this can you help me this is an assignment for school, we have to make a calculator.

Answer (score 0):

You seems to access twice :

```
let number2 = Int(label1.text!)!
let chosenSegment = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
```

And

```
let selectedSegmentIndex = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex
```

with 2 different names. Same method ? If not why not using chosenSegment

Answer (score 0):

`segmentedControl` is a function, it doesn't have a member.

But it looks like a typo, the solution is pretty easy. Delete the line

```
let chosenSegment = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
```

and replace

```
let selectedSegmentIndex = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex
```

with

```
let selectedSegmentIndex = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
```